# Day upper Bound and Lower Bound for MongoDB Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have a Database and i am saving logs as well for the each update performed by users on Database. I want to check if user is updating Data within 24 hours then update the Log, else if it's more than a day since data is updated then instead of updating the log for the day insert new log. for that i need to set upper bound and lower bound for the time on which data is inserted.

I have write down a function that will check if data is updated since 24 hours or not, but i dont know what to put as upper bound and lower bound for a day.

```
// returns 24 hours records, by Id and Crop...
    private FarmerCropDataLog findLogByIdAndCrop(Farmer farmer, Crop cropData) {

        String farmerId = farmer.getId();

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(FarmerCropDataLog.Constants.FARMER_ID).is(farmerId));
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(FarmerCropDataLog.Constants.CROP).is(Crop.valueOf(Crop.class, cropData.name())));
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(FarmerCropDataLog.Constants.CREATION_TIME).lt(UPPER_BOUND));
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(FarmerCropDataLog.Constants.CREATION_TIME).gte(LOWERBOUND));
        List<FarmerCropDataLog> logData = farmerCropDataLogDao.runQuery(query, FarmerCropDataLog.class);
        if (logData != null) {
            return logData.get(0);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Edit ->

Upper Bound should be 24*60*60*1000 and lowerBound should be 0?

Comment: Which is the type of the filed with name `FarmerCropDataLog.Constants.CREATION_TIME`? How are its values written to the database?

Comment: Its long type. I want lowerBound and upperBound for a particular day via timestamp.

Comment: Ok, clear. How is this `long` field valorized? It's an Unix timestamp, a millis timestamp, ...

Comment: I think unix timeStamp.

Comment: Ok, so your upper bound is the unix timestamp associated with the current date and time, the lower bound is the upper bound minus the duration of a day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the info in the comments, I think you can valorize bounds values as follows:

```
long millisPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
long upperBound = System.currentTimeMillis();
long lowerBound = upperBound - millisPerDay;
```

CAUTION: you should check whether you timestamp field uses Unix Timestamps (in seconds) or millis since 01/01/1970: in the first scenario, your values should be divided by 1000.

I hope this can help you tu setup your query properly...